# RDS is not working in the phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, rds

I'm trying to load the RDS in the phpMyAdmin. Therefore I edited the following parameters in the /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'RDS-ENDPOINT-URL';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'USER';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'PASSWORD';
```

But my new RDS instance is not showing up in the phpMyadmin, any idea why?

From analysis I identifies that even though renaming the /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file to something else, phpMyadmin is working without any issues. Additionally when I tried the RDS instance Endpoint in the browser URL it **says This site can’t be reached**. Is these all normal?

**EDIT**

Security Group set as

Inbound: Type -> MYSQL/Aurora          Source -> 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound: Type -> All traffic          source -> 0.0.0.0/0

FYI: I updated my Windows localhost xampp phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file and the RDS working fine.

However still with EC2 DNS URL RDS instance is not showing up.

i.e {EC2}.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Why would you think the RDS instance endpoint would be viewable in a web browser? That's a database URL not a website URL. Is the RDS security group open to the server phpMyAdmin is running on?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it'll open up something like phpMyAdmin; anyway my mistake. The security group set as (see the EDIT in my question)

Comment: So now this is no longer an RDS question but a question about accessing something running on your EC2 server? If that's the case then show your security group settings for the EC2 server.

Comment: In the RDS instance, set the following security group:
`Inbound: TCP - Web server - 3306`

In the web server, ensure that outbound connection to the RDS instance is enabled (in security group assigned to the web server)